# SQL SELECT JOIN FILTER

Tags: sql, select, join, where-clause

I try to explain the problem as good as possible.

I have multiple tables:

project, group, period.

The connection table of these three is called project_status.

I will quickly show there content

**Project**

```
| projectID | name | date |
| ------------------------|
| 1         | test | 2015 |
| 2         | test | 2015 |
```

**Group**

```
| groupID| name |
| --------------|
| 1      | ab   |
| 2      | cd   |
```

**Period**

```
| periodID  | status   |
| ---------------------|
| 1         | 0        | #inactive
| 2         | 1        | #active
| 3         | 2        | #new
```

**Project stats**

```
| projectID | groepID | periodID |
| -------------------------------|
| 1         | 1       | 2        | #active period
| 1         | 1       | 3        | #new period
```

Now in a gui you can select a period. Is the period active then i dont show the 
project because it's in use (active). Now when i select a period with status new there must be a check to determine:

- Is this project already in a new period

The problem is when i write a query there is always the active period. How could i write a query that only checks in project status for status new

i have tried the following query

```
SELECT projectID, name
FROM project
WHERE projectID IN
(
    SELECT ps.projectID
    FROM project_status as ps
    JOIN period as per
    ON ps.periodID = per.periodID
    WHERE per.status = 0
    AND per.stats != 2
)
OR projectID NOT IN
(
    SELECT projectID
    FROM project_status
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks right.
Only remove
AND per.periode_status != 2
What is periode_status ? You  didnt explain

```
WHERE per.status = 0
AND per.periode_status != 2 -- remove it
```

Comment: periode_status needs to be status it's changed

Comment: WHERE per.status = 0   AND per.status != 2
is equal
WHERE per.status = 0

So you querry is good
WHERE per.status = 0
return #inactive projects as you wish in querry 

WHERE per.status = 2
return #new

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross apply, something like this would select projectID & name where periodID = 3:

```
SELECT projectID, name FROM project a 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT projectID,periodID FROM project_status WHERE projectID = a.projectID) b 
WHERE b.periodID = 3
```