# required data from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables first is `Exhibitor_Details` & another one is `Form_Status`. In `Form_Status` table one column `Status` is available with values as `Read, Draft, Submitted`. If one form is opened then `status` of that form will be `Read` & if a Exhibitor submits that form then status will change to `submitted`.

Both the tables are linked with `Exhibitor_Details.ID`. we did not assign any value to `status` column value if an Exhibitor did not open that form(i.e. form is unread) so if Exhibitor opens that form then the value will be inserted in `Status`column.

If I have 10 Exhibitor & out of 10, two exhibitor opened the form(`status=Read`), two exhibitor saved as draft the form(`status=draft`) & other 6 did not open it (`Status` is not provided by us so this record is not available in `Form_Status` table).

I want a SQL query through join in which all exhibitor data will come except the `status=submitted` but my problem is the remaining 6 exhibitor details are  not available in `form_status` then this 6 records are not coming.

My query is

```
Select Distinct Exhibitor_Details.ID,Exhibitor_Details.Banner_Name,Form_Status.Exhibitor_ID,Form_Status.Status,Form_Status.Form_ID
from Exhibitor_Details
left join Form_Status on Exhibitor_Details.ID=Form_Status.Exhibitor_ID
where Exhibitor_Details.Edition_ID=1142 and Form_Status.Edition_ID=1142  and Form_Status.Status not in ('Submitted')
order by Form_Status.Exhibitor_ID asc
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using, please.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can i share my sample data here?

Comment: @ibrahimshaikh edit your post and add data in text format, sample input and expected output

Comment: @BHouse my expected input & output is here

Comment: @ibrahimshaikh can't see any sample data in your question

Comment: Your input data should be formatted into `INSERT` statement, so we can copy and try queries in Management Studio directly.

Comment: You can try to do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654996/sql-select-join-filter. And providing the `CREATE TABLE` statement about your table schema. And `INSERT` sample data statement. And **result** that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
left join Form_Status 
    on Exhibitor_Details.ID=Form_Status.Exhibitor_ID
```

to:

```
left join Form_Status
   on Exhibitor_Details.ID = Form_Status.Exhibitor_ID
   and Form_Status.Status != 'Submitted'
```

and remove:

```
and Form_Status.Status not in ('Submitted')
```

If you've got a LEFT JOIN and then use the 'right hand' table in the WHERE clause it usually effectively becomes an INNER JOIN.

Also you need to be careful using NOT IN if there are NULLs involved...

**Re-runnable example... the LEFT JOIN in the final statement is 'broken' by the WHERE clause.**

```
declare @t1 table (id int, txt varchar)
declare @t2 table (id int, txt varchar)

insert into @t1
select '1', 'a' union
select '2', 'b'

insert into @t2
select '1', 'c'

select *
from @t1 a
inner join @t2 b on a.id = b.id

select *
from @t1 a
left join @t2 b on a.id = b.id

-- BROKEN
select *
from @t1 a
left join @t2 b on a.id = b.id
where b.txt not in ('d')
```